# Taskserver threads in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

We have a E node group containing 3 E node hosts. We have a taskserver set up against the group containing 16 threads. Does it mean that each of these hosts have 16 threads each (which makes a total of 48 threads for 3 hosts) or the hosts have a total of not more than 16 nodes?

Also, if I set up a scheduled task (e.g. hourly) without specifying one of these hosts, would that mean that the task can potentially run on *more than one hosts at the same time* or the task would always be executed on a single host?

Apologies, if the questions have already been addressed somewhere else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread and cache settings work per host. It would be rather cumbersome to have to change all those settings whenever you add a host to a cluster. :-)

If you don't specify a host, the schedule will run on all hosts within the group, see also:

http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:group-hourly-scheduled-task

So yes, that would mean multiple hosts would be executing the same query. It could be wise to limit their work to local forests only using [xdmp:host-forests](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:host-forests), or tie the schedule to a specific host.

HTH!

Comment: Appreciate your answer @grtjn. If I understood the first part of the answer correctly, you alluded to the fact that, in my example, the total number of threads available across the board would be 48, but each host would have 16 threads, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you end up with an aggregate total of NUM_THREADS * NUM_HOSTS, organized as NUM_THREADS per host.